# higher order partial derivative notation

Tags: calculus, notation, partial-derivative

I am confusing of the notation of  $\partial^2_{xy}u$. Does $\partial^2_{xy}u$ mean $\partial_{xyxy}u$ ? Or does the $2$ simply mean the order?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that $\partial^2_{xy}$ could mean either $\partial_{x}\partial_{y}$ or $\partial_{xy}\partial_{xy}$, depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

It might be confusing for the first time
$$\partial^2_{xy}u= \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} u,$$
just different notations

Comment: I think it is extremely strange when we denote the second derivative w.r.t. x as  $\partial ^2_{x}$ while $\partial ^2_{xy}$ means second derivative w.r.t. x and y.

Comment: In a research-level paper, one might use $\partial^2_{xy}$ to represent applying the operator twice...